# How to prevent a dynamically added element from disappearing after page reload.

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which generates a div element in the html when i click the submit button. The div element gets generated successfully, but problem is when i refresh the page it disappears, how to make it stay there even when the page is refreshed later.

My purpose is i want user to add comments on my page. So i want comments to stay on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myfunction(){

        var name=document.forms["myform"]["name"].value;
        var comment = document.forms["myform"]["comment"].value;

        var div=document.createElement("div");
        var text=document.createTextNode(name+" commented "+comment);
        div.appendChild(text);

        document.body.appendChild(text);

    }

</script>

<body>
    <form name="myform">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <br>

        Comment: 
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment">
        </textarea>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfunction()"/>

    </form>


</body>
<div id = "com"></div>
```

Comment: On Page load, You have to make sure that you are loading all the comments entered before the page loaded. So there should be an Ajax call on page load that loads all the comments from the server.

Comment: But am not storing comments in the server, can you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: You need to store the comments in a database with a back end scripting system. All your script does is edit the local client's HTML DOM.

Do you know any languages other than JavaScript? PHP, Ruby, etc? How are you hosting your website?

Comment: Where are you storing the comments? Just printing them on the page?

Comment: When you say you are loading the comments div, you should have the comments stores somewhere(API? your server? etc) .. You should do the  "read" operation on every page load in addtion to an on demand read.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might even want something like this:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/

Try this, i'm using jquery though: http://jsfiddle.net/sVgxa/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Enter</button>
<div id="newDivs"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
   var text = $('#input').val();
   $('#newDivs').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
});
```

If you want something that shows up between different users you will need something more complicated using Ajax.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies. Yes, i do think they need to stored somewhere in some database. I know this in java, but i am using cPanel hosting of www.unichost.com. My plan does not support java. I never read PHP/CGI. Can you please guide?

Comment: "Supplement", your point is right, it displays correctly the text entered, but i want text to stay in further subsequent page access/refresh. Currently i am not storing comments anywhere, just printing, but i need help to store and access in some way.

Comment: Awesome, well you might benefit maximum from following the instructions in the link I posted above. That's how you will keep your comments on the page after post and refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript cookies:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2J7b/1/)

**html:**

```
<form name="myform">Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br>Comment:
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfunction()" />
    <div id="com"></div>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", check, false);

function check() {
    if (checkCookie("name")) {
        var name = document.forms["myform"]["name"].value;
        var comment = document.forms["myform"]["comment"].value;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var text = document.createTextNode(getCookie("name") + " commented " + getCookie("comment"));
        div.appendChild(text);
        document.body.appendChild(text);
    }
}

function myfunction() {
    var name = document.forms["myform"]["name"].value;
    var comment = document.forms["myform"]["comment"].value;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var text = document.createTextNode(name + " commented " + comment);
    div.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(text);
    if (!checkCookie("name")) {
        setCookie("name", name, 365);
        setCookie("comment", comment, 365);
    }
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie(cookie) {
    var flag = getCookie(cookie);
    if (flag != null && flag != "") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Vicky, I think what you have mentioned it when user adds a comment, we are storing the comment and his name in form of cookies in the user's browser. And in subsequent runs we are just retrieving them from cookies. But my point is that how would other user who is accessing the page for the first time would be able to view the comments since cookies won't be sent for him.

Comment: I think you dint mention it in your question

Comment: To do so u ll have to implement Supplement's answer